# XML to Array conversion PHP

Tags: php, xml, arrays, soap

I am some issue in conversion XML response to array in PHP.

Here is the SOAP XML response (partially given):

```
    $XMLResponse = '
<Fareportal>
<FpSearch_AirLowFaresRS>
<CntKey>1777f5a7-7824-46ce-a0f8-33d5e6e96816</CntKey>
<Currency CurrencyCode="USD"/>
<OriginDestinationOptions>
<OutBoundOptions>

<OutBoundOption segmentid="9W7008V21Feb14">
<FlightSegment FlightNumber="7008" DepartureDateTime="21Feb14T08:20 AM" ArrivalDateTime="21Feb14T09:10 AM" FlightDuration="0.50" FDType="S" StopQuantity="0" RPH="1">
<DepartureAirport LocationCode="MAA"/>
<ArrivalAirport LocationCode="BLR"/>
<Equipment AirEquipType="739"/><FlightCabin CabinType="Y"/><FlightClass ClassType="V"/><MarketingAirline Code="9W"/>
<OperatedByAirline CompanyText="JETKONNECT"/>
<Flight FlightType="O"/>
<Opaque>False</Opaque>
</FlightSegment>
</OutBoundOption>

<OutBoundOption segmentid="9W7030V21Feb2014">
<FlightSegment FlightNumber="7030" DepartureDateTime="21Feb2014T09:30 PM" ArrivalDateTime="21Feb2014T10:25 PM" FlightDuration="00.55" FDType="T" StopQuantity="0" RPH="1">
<DepartureAirport LocationCode="MAA"/>
<ArrivalAirport LocationCode="BLR"/>
<Equipment AirEquipType="739"/><FlightCabin CabinType="Y"/><FlightClass ClassType="V"/><MarketingAirline Code="9W"/>
<OperatedByAirline CompanyText="JETKONNECT"/><Flight FlightType="O"/><Opaque>False</Opaque>
</FlightSegment>
</OutBoundOption>

</OutBoundOptions>
</OriginDestinationOptions>
</FpSearch_AirLowFaresRS>
</Fareportal>
    ';
```

I need to get the flight details like FlightNumber, DepartureDateTime, ArrivalDateTime, etc.

but I tried lot of code like SimpleXMLElement, DOMDocument, simplexml_load_string all things return XML data only not in array.

Please help me on this type of XML response. Would anyone give me reference url or suggestion?

Comment: Please show us some of the code you tried

Comment: Why do you need it as an array and not as an object? You could always cast the object to an array manually (ie. `$a = (array) new simpleXML($xml);`)

Comment: hi tularis, object or array fine.

Comment: i tried, 1.$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadXML( $soapResponse );

$Results = $doc->getElementsByTagName("searchflightavailability33result");
$Result = $Results->item(0)->nodeValue; 2.simplexml_load_string($soapResponse,'SimpleXMLElement',LIBXML_NOCDATA); 3.$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($soapResponse);
foreach ($xml->children() as $second_gen) {
 echo '<pre>';print_r($second_gen);die;
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try json_decode() - https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

```
$xmlObject = simplexml_load_string($xmlString);

$array = json_decode(json_encode($xmlObject), true);
```

Hope that helps.